# Creating HLS Playlists (M3u8) Using FFmpeg

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, video, ffmpeg

I created my own bash script that will create videos on demand with different resolutions and bit rates. I used "ffmpeg" tool do that, "ffmpeg" is a must, hence I can not use any other tool.

The result of my script is:

[image]

And each folder has:

[image]

The default video and the other videos with different bit rates.

I want to create a "HLS" playlist using "ffmpeg". I found a website that shows a script that is doing all of it :

```
ffmpeg -i brooklynsfinest_clip_1080p.mp4 \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]split=3[v1][v2][v3]; \
[v1]copy[v1out]; [v2]scale=w=1280:h=720[v2out]; [v3]scale=w=640:h=360[v3out]" \
-map [v1out] -c:v:0 libx264 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1" -b:v:0 5M -maxrate:v:0 5M -minrate:v:0 5M -bufsize:v:0 10M -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
-map [v2out] -c:v:1 libx264 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1" -b:v:1 3M -maxrate:v:1 3M -minrate:v:1 3M -bufsize:v:1 3M -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
-map [v3out] -c:v:2 libx264 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1" -b:v:2 1M -maxrate:v:2 1M -minrate:v:2 1M -bufsize:v:2 1M -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
-map a:0 -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 96k -ac 2 \
-map a:0 -c:a:1 aac -b:a:1 96k -ac 2 \
-map a:0 -c:a:2 aac -b:a:2 48k -ac 2 \
-f hls \
-hls_time 2 \
-hls_playlist_type vod \
-hls_flags independent_segments \
-hls_segment_type mpegts \
-hls_segment_filename stream_%v/data%02d.ts \
-master_pl_name master.m3u8 \
-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2" stream_%v.m3u8
```

I am more focused on the last part that I can not figure it out:

```
-f hls \
-hls_time 2 \
-hls_playlist_type vod \
-hls_flags independent_segments \
-hls_segment_type mpegts \
-hls_segment_filename stream_%v/data%02d.ts \
-master_pl_name master.m3u8 \
-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2" stream_%v.m3u8
```

Does someone know how to do that in my case, I just need a ffmpeg command that works and I will be able to modified and adapted to my script.

I tried to do this, but it gives me an error:

[image]

Thank you so much for you time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `-var_stream_map` is to group media streams together. In your example, `v:0,a:0` means that video stream 1 and audio stream 1 are being grouped together.

All that's left to do is to name the streams and change the directory of the segments using `-hls_segment_filename`. To do this, update the `-var_stream_map` and `-hls_segment_filename` options like this:

```shell
-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0,name:1080p v:1,a:1,name:720p v:2,a:2,name:360p"
```

```shell
-hls_segment_filename akiyo.mp4_%v_directory/data%02d.ts
```

In these options, `%v` represents the stream name and `%02d` the segment number.

Comment: Thank you! I figure it out at the end, it was a stupid mistake. Thank you so much!